# Concurrent Session and Remember-me

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, remember-me

I did this:

1. User logged in and check Remember-me box in place1.
2. User logged in and **not** check Remember-me box in place2 with the
   **same** account, then User log out.

There is a problem:

- after user logged out in place2, user's Remember-me persistent token
  in database was deleted too (I use
  `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`).

I want to do:

- user log in and not check remember-me in place2, and then log out, it
  will not inffect the persistent token in database.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I did as follows, and it worded well!

```
public class MyRememberMeService extends PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices {
    public MyRememberMeService(String key, UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        super(key, userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        String rememberMeCookie = extractRememberMeCookie(request);
        if (rememberMeCookie == null || rememberMeCookie.length() == 0) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Logout of user "
                        + (authentication == null ? "Unknown" : authentication.getName()));
            }
            cancelCookie(request, response);
        } else {
            super.logout(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}
```